# Azure IoT hub Direct Method connect timeout

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use Direct Method to invoke device OTA
The device I am using is Quectel EC21 and subscribe to the topic "$iothub/methods/POST/#"
When I Invoke the method in Azure IoT explorer,I always get the time out fail message that "message":"Timed out waiting for device to connect."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8qhr.png)

This error message confused me since I expect my device receive the method payload through MQTT from topic "$iothub/methods/POST/#" but I received nothing.
But at he same time, I can receive normal cloud to device MQTT message through topic "devices/deviceID/messages/devicebound/#"
So, is the Direct method connection and Iot hub connection are different connection?

Comment: `$iothub/methods/POST/#` is the correct topic, and you should receive a message there. The timeout will occur if you don't to respond to the message. But if I read your question right, you are not even receiving the message on the device right now? Can you include some code?

Comment: Hi Matthijs, I am using a real IOT device, so the code is embedded C to send AT command through UART, so, I am not sure it I post code will make work. I just want to make sure that this topic **$iothub/methods/POST/#** should work like **devices/{deviceID}/messages/devicebound/#** right? since I can receive message from **devices/{deviceID}/messages/devicebound/#** but not **$iothub/methods/POST/#**

Comment: Yes, `$iothub/methods/POST/#` is correct. Your method will eventually come in as `$iothub/methods/POST/methodname/?$rid=1`. One important thing to note, if your device does receive the message but does not respond to it, IoT Hub will consider it a timeout.

Comment: actually, my problem is exactly cannot receive anything from **$iothub/methods/POST/#** on my device. I also try third party MQTT client **MQTT.fx** to  sub this topic but can get nothing neither. However, both my device and MQTT.fx can receive message from **devices/{deviceID}/messages/devicebound/#**

Comment: I understand, could you expand your question with how you authenticate with your hub? How do you structure your username, connection string and password would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Matthijs, thanks for your hint, I found I need add api version in my username as I described in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching online and hint from Matthijs.
To make the direct method work, I found need to add api version in username field as below
**For the Username field, use {iothubhostname}/{device_id}/?api-version=2018-06-30**

Comment: I'm glad you found your fix!